# Port missing in uri warning: Error opening file with Python OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, windows, opencv, video-streaming, ip-camera

I got a blunder as depicted beneath when I endeavor to stream ipcam

> "[tcp @ 000000000048c640] Port missing in uri
>   warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)"

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cv2.__file__
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:password@http://192.168.1.***/')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mus_vwhTCq0')

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    try:
     cv2.resizeWindow('Stream IP Camera OpenCV', 120300, 800)
     cv2.imshow('Stream IP Camera OpenCV',frame)
    except  Exception as ex:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print  (message)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

First open VLC player and ensure your ipcam stream link is working. If it works, we can now check if OpenCV can connect to the camera with `isOpened()` and check the frame retrieval status:

```
while True:
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Process here
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with making the url working in VLC. Try [this website](http://www.ispyconnect.com/sources.aspx) to get a working link/port/user/password combination that works for you camera.