# cv2.VideoCapture "Port missing in uri" only on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-capture, rtsp

I'm trying to connect to a RTSP camera via OpenCV using VideoCapture from opencv-python and i get the following error ONLY IN PYTHON3, IT WORKS NORMALLY IN PYTHON2:

```
[tcp @ 0x1d0a4ac0] Port missing in uri
Unable to open
```

The code:

```
import cv2

endpoint = "rtsp://<user>:<password>@192.168.<ip>.<ip>:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(endpoint)

if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Unable to open")
else:
        print("Open")
```

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling opencv-python
- Reinstalling Python and all it's dependencies and packages (`apt install python-opencv`)
- Checking the RTSP connection and authentication (It works fine only in Python2)
- Checked for [Port missing in uri warning: Error opening file with Python OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451597/port-missing-in-uri-warning-error-opening-file-with-python-opencv-cv2-videocapt)
- Checked for [cv2.videoCapture only return "Port missing in uri"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833545/cv2-videocapture-only-return-port-missing-in-uri)

I'm running this in a NVidia Jetson Xavier AGX running Ubuntu.

Any suggestion to fix this will be welcome

(And, YES, I NEED it to run on Python3)

Comment: Have you tried with a different URI format? e.g. `rtsp://192.168.<ip>.<ip>:554/cam/realmonitor?user=<user>&password=<password>&channel=1&subtype=0`

Comment: @pazitos10 it doesn't work, unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error only in a newer version of opencv.

It worked for me in python3 with an older version, so I pinned the older version to my requirements.

```
opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==4.1.1.26 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==4.1.1.26

Comment: yeah these are chaos... depending on the platform/architecture that you're deploying to, there may be different versions available to install with pip. I would try going with one of the near versions that are listed in that error message